# After printing the session value, I unset the session value, but the session still prints a blank value

Tags: php, session

I am using below code for setting session value.

```
    if (!isset($_SESSION['flash_messages'])) {
        $_SESSION['flash_messages'] = array();
    }

    $_SESSION['flash_messages'][] = array(
        'type' => 'success',
        'message' => 'Data Created Successfully'
    );
    header("Location: /customFeatures");
```

And then I am fetching flash message in template file and printing it

```
    if (isset($_SESSION['flash_messages']) && count($_SESSION['flash_messages']) > 0) 
    {
      $html = '';
      foreach ($_SESSION['flash_messages'] as $flashMessage) {
         $type = $flashMessage['type'];
         $message = $flashMessage['message'];
         $html .=  "<div class='alert alert-{$type}'><div>" . $message . "</div></div>";
     }
      echo $html;
      unset($_SESSION['flash_messages']);
    }
```

Now problem is that, if I am remove **unset($_SESSION['flash_messages']);** this line then flash message shown properly but if I kept as it is then session prints blank value.

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you saying that using `unset()` _after_ you've already echoed the Session value causes the value not to be shown in the place where you echoed it? That doesn't make any sense, and I would be surprised if anyone can reproduce that. Are you sure that's really what is happening? I think maybe you need to do a bit more investigation. Make sure you post a [mre] of the issue...I am 99% certain this code won't be one (although, as always, happy to be proved wrong). Thanks.

Comment: @ADyson I am also surprised that how it is possible...I am echoed session variable before unset still not getting session..and just I remove unset($_SESSION['flash_messages']) line it is working properly.

Comment: As I suspected, I can't reproduce it using the code you've given us - demo: https://3v4l.org/cRiJc . Obviously that example doesn't involve the redirect, but since Session values are persisted between requests, that shouldn't matter. You must be mistaken somehow in your diagnosis. There is a coincidence perhaps, and the root cause lies elsewhere. Re-examine your code, and your assumptions about it. I don't think there is much else we can do to help you, without more info.

Comment: @ADyson I am using my custom MVC framework. I am setting flash message from controller and displaying in common view file. So I think there is something issue with my framework code.

Comment: Maybe. As I said, we cannot do much without a [mre] of the issue (see also [ask]). Happy to help if we can, but right now we cannot do anything without more details.